# Domain / subdomain sitemap

Tags: html, xml

I have a website that has basic information on the main domain

```
mydomain.com/about
mydomain.com/contact
mydomain.com/services
```

In also have a subdomain with a ton of information / products that I would love to have included in my sitemap.

```
shop.mydomain.com
```

Is it possible to incorporate the subdomain (shop.mydomain.com) in the sitemap xml for mydomain.com?

What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not mix multiple domains/subdomains in the same XML sitemap file :(